Azure Databricks Key Vault Backed Secret Scope using managed identity
If I have an Azure key vault with Azure role-based access control (recommended) access control,
I want to enable Azure backed secrets scope Either by using a service principal or managed identity, How do I go about it

Could you please provide your approach if you have tried anything?

You can follow below procedure to achieve your requirement:
Go to Azure key vault Access control (IAM), click on Add, select Add role assignment, select key vault Administrator role, check user, group, service principle, search for AzureDatabricks, select it and click on Review+assign button as shown below:

After successful role assignment, create secret scope with required details as shown below:

You will be able to access key vault secrets success fully as shown below:
databricks secrets list-scopes
databricks secrets list --scope <scopeName>



@John Kiragu can you check above answer,does it helped or not? Let me know.
